# blogger post from php

Tags: php

Помогите разобраться с blogger api :( . Пытаюсь разместить пост из php - выдаёт ошибку Expected response code 200, got 401 User does not have permission to create new post or page . Пользователь - владелец блога. Чяднт?

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Query');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');

function createPublishedPost($title='Hello, world!', $content='I am blogging 
on the internet.')
{
  $user = 'логин';
  $pass = 'пароль';
  $service = 'blogger';
  $blogID = "идентификатор блога";

  $client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, $service, null,
        Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::DEFAULT_SOURCE, null, null,
        Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::CLIENTLOGIN_URI, 'GOOGLE');
  $gdClient = new Zend_Gdata($client);

  $uri = 'http://www.blogger.com/feeds/' . $blogID . '/posts/default';
  $entry = $gdClient->newEntry();
  $entry->title = $gdClient->newTitle($title);
  $entry->content = $gdClient->newContent($content);
  $entry->content->setType('text');

  $createdPost = $gdClient->insertEntry($entry, $uri);
  $idText = split('-', $createdPost->id->text);
  $newPostID = $idText[2];

  return $newPostID;
}

echo createPublishedPost();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось что это не возможно. Требуется использовать Blogger Api + Google oAuth 2.0 . После чего можно разместить пост. Единственное что в итоге не понятно - как это чудо вызвать из консоли.